# Spring @RequestMapping value explicit/implicit

Tags: java, spring, jls

In some cases I have seen two different ways to specify uri in `@RequestMapping`:

1. `@RequestMapping(value="/somepath")`
2. `@RequestMapping("/somepath")`

The latter is often used at class level. So, is it always legal omitting the `value` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Java Language Spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.3) states

> It is legal to use single-element annotations for annotation types with multiple elements, so long as one element is named value, and all other elements have default values.

Since `@RequestMapping` has a defined `value` attribute and all other attributes have default values (empty arrays), it is always legal to omit spelling the name `value` if you don't specify any other attributes for the annotation:

```
@RequestMapping("/somepath") // valid
@RequestMapping("/somepath",  method = RequestMethod.GET) // INVALID!
```

Comment: Thank you, very exhaustive!

Comment: If you like it, perhaps you would like to upvote it (arrow up) on the side of the answer? And if this answers your question to your satisfaction you might mark it as "accepted answer".

Answer (score 0):

For `@RequestMapping` annotation **value** is the primary attribute, it is mandatory.

`1)@RequestMapping(value="/somepath")`:
Here you can mention remaining attributes, for ex: method,produces
`2) @RequestMapping("/somepath")`:
Here you can not mention rest of the attributes, as by default `"/somepath"` will be taken as value attribute.

[Check this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html)